# I'm trying to cancel the tasks in running event loop using python asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Hi I'm stuck the problem asyncio. I'm using Python version 3.7.3.
And Sorry for I'm not native speaker at English.

I'm writing a script for get a lyric from genius.

This is my script.
Every requests going to be 6times if I couldn't the result in the end.
I divided get request 2 times almost same time. It means like a 2*3.

Checking the result and if I could get the result I want to stop the other tasks.
Because of to be less request.
So I used `cancel()` and tried to raise `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` when I got the lyric but It doesn't work well.
It shows `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` I don't know why doesn't work well.
Please teach me some one familiar with this situation.

```
import asyncio
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


#Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-2

class Lyric():
    def __init__(self, artist, song_name):
        self.artist = artist
        self.song_name = song_name
        self.__gtask = []
        self.__canceled = False
        self.__lyric = ''

        
        self.genius_url = self.make_genius_url(artist, song_name)
        lyric = self.lyric_from_genius(self.genius_url)
        print(lyric)
    
    def make_genius_url(self, artist, song_name):
        search_song = f'{artist} {song_name}'
        search_song = search_song.replace(' ', '-')
        print(search_song)
        return f'https://genius.com/{search_song}-lyrics'
    

    def get_soup(self, url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
            return soup
        else:
            return False
    
    def scrape_genius(self, url):
        soup = self.get_soup(url)
        if soup and not self.__canceled:
            lyric_soup = soup.select('.song_body-lyrics .lyrics p')
            if lyric_soup:
                self.__canceled = True
                tags = lyric_soup[0].find_all(['a', 'i'])
                for tag in tags:
                    tag.unwrap()
                print('ここから歌詞です。')
                print(lyric_soup[0].text)
                self.__lyric = lyric_soup[0].text
                self.__gtask.cancel()
            else:
                print('歌詞情報を取得出来なかった。')
        else:
            if self.__canceled:
                print('歌詞取得した')
            else:
                print('歌詞情報がない')
            self.__gtask.cancel()


    def lyric_from_genius(self, url):

        async def main_loop(url):
            sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
            async def get_lyric_soup(url):
                async with sem:
                    await self.loop.run_in_executor(None, self.scrape_genius, url)
            
            #main_loopの処理       
            for _ in range(6):
                self.__gtask += [get_lyric_soup(url)]
            return await asyncio.gather(*self.__gtask)
        
        try:
            self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            self.loop.run_until_complete(main_loop(url))
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError as e:
            print("*** CancelledError ***", e)
        finally:
            if self.__lyric:
                return self.__lyric
            else:
                print('5回のリクエストで曲情報が取れなかった。')
        
        


Lyric = Lyric('kamal', 'blue')
```

Comment: You don't really use asyncio because requests is not an async http library. `run_in_executor` instructs asyncio to use **threads** to perform the work, and then cancellation doesn't work. Switch to aiohttp, get rid of `run_in_executor` (which you'll then no longer need), and things will work as intended.

Comment: @wataru Does aiohttp work?

Comment: I don't know I don't use aiohttp and I know `run_in_executor` using thread It's ok for me. Is that True??  >cancellation doesn't work. I saw some one using cancellation at kind of my code.